# ball animation with if

Tags: javascript, animation

I'm working with an animation where each time the ball hits `maxY` it would jump up for half of the height last time. However when I tried to do this, it would not work.

```
var imgBall = document.getElementById("imgBall");

var count = 0;

var dy = 2;
var dx = 1;

var ballY = imgBall.offsetTop;
var ballX = imgBall.offsetLeft;
imgBall.style.width = 50 + "px";
imgBall.style.height = 50 + "px";

var minX = 0
var maxX = 700;
var minY = 0;
var maxY = 500;

setInterval(ballAnimation, 10);

function ballAnimation() {

if ((count == 0) && (ballY == maxY)) {
    dy = dy * -1;
    count++;
}
if (ballY == maxY / 2 - imgBall.offsetWidth / 2) {
    dy = dy * -1;
}

ballY = ballY + dy;
ballX = ballX + dx;

imgBall.style.top = ballY + "px";
imgBall.style.left = ballX + "px";
}
```

this is the part where it fails `if (ballY == maxY / 2 - imgBall.offsetWidth / 2)`. I have tried to test it and when i write `if (ballY == maxY / 2)`it would work totally fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is of logical nature, you increment (or decrement) `ballY` of `dy` (2) at every iteration. In this specific scenario `maxY / 2 - imgBall.offsetWidth / 2` is 225, that means that you never meet the condition as true. A quick fix is to change  the check as follows:

```
ballY >= maxY / 2 - imgBall.offsetWidth / 2
```

replacing `==` with `>=` you can catch the position even if it goes over the border.